# Find String Pattern Match in Pandas Dataframe and Return Matched Strin

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe column with variable comma separated text and just trying to extract the values that are found based on another list. So my dataframe looks like this:

```
col1 | col2
-----------
 x   | a,b


listformatch = [c,d,f,b]
pattern = '|'.join(listformatch)

def test_for_pattern(x):
    if re.search(pattern, x):
        return pattern
    else:
        return x

#also can use col2.str.contains(pattern) for same results
```

The above filtering works great but instead of returning `b` when it finds the match it returns the whole pattern such as `a|b` instead of just `b` whereas I want to create another column with the pattern it finds such as `b`.

Here is my final function but still getting `UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract." groups, use str.extract.", UserWarning)` I wish I can solve:

```
def matching_func(file1, file2):
    file1 = pd.read_csv(fin)
    file2 = pd.read_excel(fin1, 0, skiprows=1)
    pattern = '|'.join(file1[col1].tolist())
    file2['new_col'] = file2[col1].map(lambda x: re.search(pattern, x).group()\
                                             if re.search(pattern, x) else None)
```

I think I understand how pandas extract works now but probably still rusty on regex. How do I create a pattern variable to use for the below example:

```
df[col1].str.extract('(word1|word2)')
```

Instead of having the words in the argument, I want to create variable as `pattern = 'word1|word2'` but that won't work because of the way the string is being created.

My final and preferred version with vectorized string method in pandas 0.13:

*Using values from one column to extract from a second column:*

```
df[col1].str.extract('({})'.format('|'.join(df[col2]))
```

Comment: Try `re.search(pattern, x).group(0)` instead

Answer (score 3):

You might like to use extract, or one of the other [vectorised string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['a', 'a,b'])

In [12]: s.str.extract('([cdfb])')
Out[12]:
0    NaN
1      b
dtype: object
```

Comment: extract seems great. how would I use it though if I am getting the string matches from another dataframe column. In other words, for my function above I did `'|'.join(df[col1].tolist())` to get my pattern.

Comment: any idea how I can get rid of this message from my program: `UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract." groups, use str.extract.", UserWarning)`

Comment: @prometheus2305 yup, put parentheses around what you're trying to find (as in my example) :)

Comment: @prometheus2305 a DataFrame column is just a Series, so you can do `df[col1].str.extract('([cdfb])')`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If I wanted to extract phrases that appear in a column based on passing an argument to extract with all of the potential phrases to find how would I construct the variable? I've added the example to the question.

Comment: @prometheus2305 I think you're looking for `'(%s)' % '|'.join(patterns)` where `patterns = ['word1', 'word2']` ?

Comment: Wow. this code seems so strange but perfectly worked for what I needed. Thank you! `pattern = '({})'.format('|'.join(df[col1].tolist()))`

Comment: @prometheus2305 note that the tolist call is not needed :)